# What is the difference between a ligand and a co-ligand?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, terminology

I've seen the word co-ligand pop up in several papers. Is there a particular difference between a co-ligand and a ligand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this refers to situations in tranistion metal complexes where there is more than one kind of ligand, and specifically, where one of the coligands could not ligate and endure by itself due to reactivity, such as a carbene being blocked from reactivity due to a coligands steric bulk